# Java (Regex?) split string between number/letter combination

Tags: java, regex, string, split, explode

I've been looking through pages and pages of Google results but haven't come across anything that could help me.

What I'm trying to do is split a string like `Bananas22Apples496Pears3`, and break it down into some kind of readable format. Since `String.split()` cannot do this, I was wondering if anyone could point me to a regex snippet that could accomplish this.

Expanding a bit: the above string would be split into (`String[]` for simplicity's sake):

```
{"Bananas:22", "Apples:496", "Pears:3"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
String s = "Bananas22Apples496Pears3";

String[] res = s.replaceAll("(?<=\\p{L})(?=\\d)", ":").split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\p{L})");
    for (String t : res) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
```

The first step would be to replace the empty string with a ":", when on the left is a letter with the [lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<=\\p{L})` and on the right is a digit, with the [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=\\d)`.

Then split the result, when on the left is a digit and on the right is a letter.

`\\p{L}` is a [Unicode property](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) that matches every letter in every language.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `Replace` and then `split` the string.You can't do it with the split alone

**1>** `Replace All` the string with the following regex

```
(\\w+?)(\\d+)
```

and replace it with

```
$1:$2
```

**2>** Now `Split` it with this regex

```
(?<=\\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

Comment: I'm not exactly hot with Regex, I tried a pattern.compile using that pattern, but I get an "invalid escape sequence" error.

Comment: @Timr you didnt escaped it like this `"\\w+?\\d+"`

Comment: @Timr it would certainly help if you would read the Java Pattern examples. I bet they teach you escaping, too...

Comment: `(?<=\:\d+)` will not work in Java, since it allows only finite length lookbehind.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

String d = "Bananas22Apples496Pears3"

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]+|[0-9]+");

Matcher m = p.matcher(d);

while (m.find()) {
      System.out.println(m.group());
}

// Bananas
// 22
// Apples
// 496
// Pears
// 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `\d+` by `:$0` and then split at `(?=[a-zA-Z]+:\d+)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String myText = "Bananas22Apples496Pears3";
System.out.println(myText.replaceAll("([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+)", "$1:$2,"));
```