# How to separate a number from String using regular expression in java?

Tags: java, regex

I already known that that the number can be split easily from String.But i am having problem in regular expression.I am having a String like this,

```
Call Numbers:
US Toll Free: 1-866-394-4524
UK Toll Free: 08081681755
India Toll Free: 180030121212
Mobile Number: 04412345678
Mobile Number: 08012345678  
Conference Bridge: 12345678
```

Dial the Dial–In number for your location and when prompted enter the conference code followed by #

I want to display it like this :

```
18663944524    
08081681755    
180030121212    
04412345678    
08012345678    
123456789
```

Any answer will be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java (Regex?) split string between number/letter combination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374171/java-regex-split-string-between-number-letter-combination)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us.

Answer (score 1):

```
final Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("[\\w\\s]+:\\s+([\\d\\-]+)?\\s*");
```

Keep in mind that `([\\d\\-]+)` is a group, and we can grab it.
Matching on this should work:

```
String line = // the current line in the file..

Matcher matcher = myPattern.matcher(line);
if (matcher.matches()) {
  String theNumber = matcher.group(1);
  System.out.println("We matched!!!: " + theNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this:

```
String phoneStr="US Toll Free: 1-866-394-4524";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(phoneStr);
while(m.find()) {
   System.out.print(phoneStr.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
18663944524
```

Source: Internet. I used this code for one of my projects. I tested for all of your inputs, it worked fine.

Comment: @user2841300, Sorry typo. Edited :)

Answer (score 0):

The easy and dirty way would be to replace all non-numerical characters, save from return carriages, with an empty `String`.

Here's an example:

```
// your original text
String text = "Call Numbers: \n" + "US Toll Free: 1-866-394-4524\n"
        + "UK Toll Free: 08081681755\n" + "India Toll Free: 180030121212\n"
        + "Mobile Number: 04412345678\n" + "Mobile Number: 08012345678\n\n" +
            "Conference Bridge: 12345678";
// prints the replacement
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("[\\D&&[^\n]]", ""));
```

Output:

```
18663944524
08081681755
180030121212
04412345678
08012345678

12345678
```

Note that there's still whitespace to post-process in this output, namely the 1st return carriage and the double return carriage between the last two lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can strip out all non-number-containing lines and all non-digits in one line:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[ :a-zA-Z-]", "").replaceAll("(?m)^$\n", "");
```

Here's some test code:

```
String str = "Call Numbers: \n" + "US Toll Free: 1-866-394-4524\n"
    + "UK Toll Free: 08081681755\n" + "India Toll Free: 180030121212\n"
    + "Mobile Number: 04412345678\n" + "Mobile Number: 08012345678\n\n" +
        "Conference Bridge: 12345678";
str = str.replaceAll("[ :a-zA-Z-]", "").replaceAll("(?m)^$\n", "");
System.out.println(":"+str);
```

Output (there are blank lines):

```
18663944524
08081681755
180030121212
04412345678
08012345678
12345678
```

Comment: ok.But i want it in seperate line

Comment: You can just not replace the newline, and remove blank line instead.

Comment: This *does* retain the new lines. See code and output

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.replaceAll`. Do it as

```
str.replaceAll("\\D","");
```

`\D` stands for anything except digit.

For each string `str` it returns all digits in `str` by replacing every other character with empty string.