# How to split a string with numbers in java

Tags: java, split

I have string `"ali22mehdi35abba1lala2"`. I want to split it to `{"ali","mehdi","abba","lala"};`
How should I do that ?

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374171/java-regex-split-string-between-number-letter-combination) and another place. I can't acheive my end.

Comment: Show us your attempts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a String in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try following code

```
String string="ali22mehdi35abba1lala2";
String tok[]=string.split("\\d+");
```

Now tok would have the split array from numbers.

Comment: @Eirenaios keep it up

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
String[] phNo = "ali22mehdi35abba1lala2".split("\\d+");
```